# Simple_form passing params to controller - no model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, parameter-passing, simple-form

I'm trying to pass a value to the controller as a parameter from a simple_form but I'm not able to read the value out. My example form is as such:

```
<%= simple_form_for 'page_contact_path', :method => "GET" do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Form' %>
<% end %>
```

Controller looks as such:

```
def contact
  @name = params[:name]
end
```

I am able to access the param using just a regular form_for tag:

```
<%= form_for 'page_contact_path', :method => "POST" do |f| %>
    <%= label_tag :name, "Full Name: " %>
    <%= text_field_tag :name %><br/>
    <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

In my view I am just accessing the instance variable @name to see if anything is passed over. Using form_for I am able to get the value back to the view but simple_form passes back nothing.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass object for example `@contact` to simple_form

```
<%= simple_form_for @contact, path: 'page_contact_path' do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name %>
  <%= f.button :submit, 'Submit Form' %>
<% end %>
```

**EDIT**

but if you haven't model for object and you need form just for getting parameter `:name` use `form_for` with rails helpers [text_field_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-text_field_tag)

Comment: If i do that, I get an null error. I do not have a model either right now. Would I need to have a Contact object or is there a work-around? @Oleg

Comment: So basically simple_form needs an object to work... Got it. Thanks!